# VMWare-Tools Installation fails on Ubuntu 11.04

Tags: ubuntu, vmware, vmware-tools

I am trying to install **VMwareTools-8.4.6-385536.tar.gz (VMWare Tools)** on the following operating system:
**Ubuntu 11.04** - 
 
Linux ubuntu 2.6.38-8-generic #42-Ubuntu SMP Mon Apr 11 03:31:50 UTC 2011 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux 
I am using **VMPlayer version 3.1.4 - build 385536**

====================================================================

After starting the installation i am getting the following errors:

What is the directory that contains the init scripts? 
[/etc/init.d]

Error opening   No such file or directory

================================================

Distribution provided drivers for Xorg X server are used.

Skipping X configuration because X drivers are not included.

Creating a new initrd boot image for the kernel.
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-2.6.38-8-generic
Starting VMware Tools services in the virtual machine:
   Switching to guest configuration:                                   done
   Blocking file system:                                               done
**Guest operating system daemon:                                     failed**
   Virtual Printing daemon:                                            done
Unable to start services for VMware Tools

Can somebody help in this?

Answer (score 0):

Are you installing the tools as `root`? If so, then let's start with the init.d problem, does that directory exist? Will you post the output of `ls -la /etc/init.d`?